# Login page goes directly to the site without checking credentials

Tags: php, session-variables, login-script

I am currently having a problem in which the login page to my website goes directly to the homepage without checking the users credentials stored in my data base. The code I use to register the users works just fine but for some reason I cant get this working properly.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
    $dbuser = 'mredd';
    $dbpass = 'csc255pass';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    //mysql_select_db( 'USERS_DB' );
    if(! $conn )
        {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db("USERS_DB",$conn);

    if (!$db_selected)
     {
        die ("Can\'t use test_db : " . mysql_error());
     }


    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];


$sql="SELECT * FROM log_tbl Where username='$user' AND password='$pass'";
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

$row = mysql_num_rows($retval);
if ($row == 1)
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
    header("Location: homepage.php");

    }   
  ?>
```

Comment: Run your code through an auto-indenter and see if you spot the error ;)

Answer (score 0):

Doh! You fell into the trap of not using brackets with your If statement. The final chunk should read

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM log_tbl Where username='$user' AND password='$pass'";
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

$row = mysql_num_rows($retval);
if ($row == 1) { //need this bracket
  $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
  header("Location: homepage.php");
 }  //and this one
} // this closes the 'POST' clause
?>
```

The code you wrote will only set the session if the row is returned, and will ALWAYS redirect to homepage.php. An If statement without brackets only controls the next command.

Comment: Yep that did it. It works fine now lol. Cant believe I made such a simple mistake. Thank you for your help